# I tried to make a stair command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, command, discord.py, bots

i tried to make a stairs command in discord.py, it should look like this:

```
---
   I
----
    I
```

etc...

but i get a error:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS E:\Hyper Bot> & C:/Users/merli/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe "e:/Hyper Bot/Hyper bot.py"
File "e:/Hyper Bot/Hyper bot.py", line 183
time.sleep 1
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

This is my code:

````
async def stairs(ctx):
   i = 1
   while True:
       ctx.send(i * '-')
       ctx.send(i * ' ' + 'I')
       i = i + 2
       time.sleep 1 ```
````

Comment: `time.sleep(1)` You're missing the parentheses.

Comment: And you are missing `await` before `ctx.send`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is `time.sleep 1` because of missing parenthesis as John Gordon pointed out. However I'd like to add that you should not use `time.sleep` at all.

See time is a synchronous library, when you use `time.sleep` your whole bot will sleep and won't respond to users or get events.

You should use `await asyncio.sleep` instead. It's used in the same way and you import the library the same with `import asyncio`.

Comment: okay this worked, thank you but now i have another error it says:
e:/Hyper Bot/Hyper bot.py:181: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited
  ctx.send(i * '-')
e:/Hyper Bot/Hyper bot.py:182: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited
  ctx.send(i * ' ' + 'I')

Comment: Read the error, it says "send" what's never awaited. `await` it